# sshpass not working with cron tab

Tags: linux, cron, sshpass

I have a script with following line

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@server "touch /tmp/test"
```

this works, when I run the script, but if I put the script in cron it doesen't work. any ideas ?

Comment: What does the cron entry look like? Are you putting it in your own, root's crontab (using sudo) of that of some other user?

Comment: Is it getting an error? Any output from the cron job should be sent to you as email (I hope you're not redirecting the output to /dev/null).

Answer (score 5):

Since this is the first answer on google, give sshpass absolute path like `/usr/bin/sshpass`. you can get the path by `which sshpass`. I also added `/usr/bin/ssh` to be sure.

Comment: This answer should be accepted. It works.

Answer (score 4):

It worked after adding -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server "touch /tmp/test"
```